# Receive address in python

Tags: python

I'm working on python, how can I receive a website address? I have tried but it doesn't work.

I have this:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(name)
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: `" how can I recive a website adress?"` what do you mean by this? get the url? get the ip address? get the content of the site?

Comment: i mean the ip adress like 123.456.78.9 and i have the code used it should work?

Comment: `name` is a variable that isn't defined in your snippet. Add `name = 'google.com'` at the top and try again

Comment: @brianpck you saved me thanks man! i found the snippet on google nad it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

The gethostbyname(hostname) method translates a host name to an IPv4 address format. The IPv4 address is returned as a string.

So the argument for this method has to be a host name like "www.python.org". Assign a hostname for the 'name' variable in string format in your code. 
Ex. `name = "www.python.org"`

Hope this helps!